# On scroll tableview cell content is change

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When i scroll tableview, the content of tableview cell are changed

```
TBDCreateGamePlayerCell * playerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if (!playerCell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TBDCreateGamePlayerCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    playerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}
```

when i am select the cell, color of cell is changed in code,
but when scroll cell color not changed.
Image of cell also change in cell when scroll.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark top answer, any answer that has helped you. If none have helped, add a comment to ask further details or explain something further. Other people facing the same issue will want to know what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

When the tableView scrolls the cells get re-initialised inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` callback.

You will need to track this state and then apply this change to your cell in the callback. Something like this:

```
TBDCreateGamePlayerCell *playerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if (!playerCell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TBDCreateGamePlayerCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    playerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}

if([self.selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [playerCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This most definitly comes from your -`cellForRow` method where I assume you have an `if` statement.

```
if (thisAndThat){
    //Set  color
}
```

Just add an else and set it to the regular color.

```
if (thisAndThat){
    //Set  color
}else{

    //Set default color !
}
```

This is because your cells are reused and once the cell had a color,  but the content doesn't comply with your IF, there is no color re-set.

If my assumption is wrong, just set the cell color in the `-cellForRow` anyway, so every time it's re-used you're certain it'll be assigned the original color and not the color that was changed from somewhere else (a selection, a notification, something)

So just this in your `-cellForRow:`
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];  //Or any other color of course.